# Insert into two referencing tables by selecting from a single table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, common-table-expression, sql-returning

I have 2 permanent tables in my PostgreSQL 12 database with a one-to-many relationship (`thing`, and `thing_identifier`). The second -- `thing_identifier` -- has a column referencing `thing`, such that `thing_identifier` can hold multiple, external identifiers for a given `thing`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thing
(
    thing_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    thing_name TEXT, --this is not necessarily unique
    thing_attribute TEXT --also not unique 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thing_identifier
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    thing_id integer references thing (thing_id),
    identifier text
);
```

I need to insert some new data into `thing` and `thing_identifier`, both of which come from a table I created by using `COPY` to pull the contents of a large CSV file into the database, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS things_to_add
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    guid TEXT, --a unique identifier used by the supplier
    thing_name TEXT, --not unique
    thing_attribute TEXT --also not unique

);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO things_to_add (guid, thing_name) VALUES 
  ('[111-22-ABC]','Thing-a-ma-jig','pretty thing'),
  ('[999-88-XYZ]','Herk-a-ma-fob','blue thing');
```

The goal is to have each row in `things_to_add` result in one new row, each, in `thing` and `thing_identifier`, as in the following:

`thing`:

```
| thing_id | thing_name          |  thing attribute  |
|----------|---------------------|-------------------|
|     1    | thing-a-ma-jig      |  pretty thing
|     2    | herk-a-ma-fob       |  blue thing
```

`thing_identifier`:

```
| id | thing_id | identifier       |
|----|----------|------------------|
|  8 |     1    | '[111-22-ABC]'   |
|  9 |     2    | '[999-88-XYZ]'   |
```

I could use a CTE `INSERT`statement (with `RETURNING thing_id`) to get the `thing_id` that results from the `INSERT` on `thing`, but I can't figure out how to get *both* that `thing_id` from the `INSERT` on `thing` *and* the original `guid` from `things_to_add`, which needs to go into `thing_identifier.identifier`.

Just to be clear, the only guaranteed unique column in `thing` is `thing_id`, and the only guaranteed unique column in `things_to_add` is `id` (which we don't want to store) and `guid` (which is what we want in `thing_identifier.identifier`), so there isn't any way to join `thing` and `things_to_add` after the `INSERT` on `thing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the thing_to_add.guid from a `JOIN` :

```
WITH list AS
(
  INSERT INTO thing (thing_name)
  SELECT thing_name
    FROM things_to_add
  RETURNING thing_id, thing_name
)
INSERT INTO thing_identifier (thing_id, identifier)
SELECT l.thing_id, t.guid
  FROM list AS l
 INNER JOIN thing_to_add AS t
    ON l.thing_name = t.thing_name
```

Then, if `thing.thing_name` is not unique, the problem is more tricky. Updating both tables `thing` and `thing_identifier` from the same trigger on `thing_to_add` may solve the issue :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_insert_thing_to_add ()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
WITH list AS
(
  INSERT INTO thing (thing_name)
  SELECT NEW.thing_name
  RETURNING thing_id
)
INSERT INTO thing_identifier (thing_id, identifier)
SELECT l.thing_id, NEW.guid
  FROM list AS l ;
$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert ON thing_to_add ;
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert 
  AFTER INSERT
  ON thing_to_add 
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_insert_thing_to_add ();
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `thing.thing_name` is not unique. Apologies if that was not clear from the description. In the actual table in my database that's represented here by `thing`, there are many columns, but the only column that's guaranteed to be unique is `thing_id`. Similarly, the `thing_name` column in `things_to_add` is not unique, either.

Comment: The amended solution (which is quite clever!) worked with a bit of tweaking. Since I already have the records in `things_to_add`, I just made the trigger into an update trigger, and can perform a trivial update to get it to fire, writing my records as needed to my two permanent tables. Thanks!